# Configuring Personal Site Quota Per User

Tags: 2010, my-site, configuration, quota

Initially, I would like all users to have the default Personal Site quota, which is 100 MB. Per user request, I would like to increase this quota to 500 MB for that individual user only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a new quota for 500mb. In Central Admin, you'd simply set that users my site site collection to that new quota.